# Laravel. Using browser back button

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I have noticed strange thing, when user clicks back button in his browser. Usually when I name my route i do this:
`Route::get('/comment', 'CommentController@getComment');` for get method.
 And:
 `Route::post('/comment-post', 'CommentController@postComment');`
for post method.
 After posting 4 comments, if user clicks back button, browser redirects him back by one post method with old inputs, by this example it happens four times. Shouldn't browser redirect user back to last view? Could you explain what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.
I'm using Laravel 5

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong. Browsers cache pages. Your user is viewing a cached previous page. The best solution is to forget that happens and just let it be, nothing wrong can happen. You cannot control how people use browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Route to a page that will handle the posting of your comment, it is actually taking the user to a new page ('/comment-post'), which means that it gets put onto the stack in the browser. So when they click the back button, it's going to take them to the top of the stack, aka the last post.

What I would recommend is using `Route::controller` and then handling the various methods inside of the CommentController class.

```
Route::controller('/comment', CommentController);
```

Then inside of CommentController:

```
public function getCommentPost()
{
  # handle posting here
}
```

What this will do is listen for the url '/comment/comment-post' and when that url is reached, it will call this method with associating camelCasing. While this MAY help with the back button issue, its just a cleaner way of handling a lot of routes.

Comment: I red few posts about that using Route::controller isin't proper way. But anyway thanks :)